# Mostrar y ocultar menú en su modo SmartPhone (responsivo)

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estoy estudiando (por mi cuenta) diseño web y programación, y estoy en el punto de agregar JavaScript a mi sitio web en desarrollo. Y pues estoy buscando la manera de hacer visible el menú en modo SmartPhone, pues quisiera que el menú al estar en dicho modo esté oculto con CSS. Fácil solo un `display:none` y con JS estuve tratando de usar

```
document.getElementById("ejemplo").style.display="block";
```

para que cuando el usuario dé click en la populares 3 barritas del menú contraído pues se expandan. Hasta ahora solo tengo un pequeño boceto de la página con el siguiente código:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.65);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.imga {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5%;
}

.imga img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #EFEFEF;
  display: none;
}

.btn a {
  color: #EFEFEF;
}

.banner {
  font-size: 35px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5%;
}

.banner a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 2%;
}

.links {
  color: #EFEFEF;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0.4%;
  margin: 0.4%;
}

.links a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 10px;
}

.links a:hover {
  background-color: #5000AD;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  animation: loop 2s infinite linear alternate;
}

@-moz-keyframes loop {
  0% {
    color: white;
  }
  100% {
    color: #5000AD;
  }
}


/*Vista para Tablet*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .banner a {
    display: none;
  }
}


/*Vista Pra Telefono*/

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .banner a {
    display: none;
  }
  .links a {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    border-bottom: black solid 1px;
    margin-right: 15%;
    display: block;
  }
  /*agrego un border top al boton de inicio*/
  #a {
    border-top: black solid 1px;
  }
  .imga {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8%;
    margin-top: 2%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Modular Desing</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--Incono Pestaña-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icons/logo.png">
    <!--META INFO!-->
    <meta name="description" content="Diseño Grafico y WEB">
    <meta name="keywords" content="over, visual, overvisual, diseño, 3d, cg, programacion, modelado, renderizado">
    <!--Hoja de Estilo Base (Solo lo simple)!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!--Hoja Para Todos Los Logos!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="contenedor">
      <!--Modulo BARRA DE NAVEGACION
  <img class="icono" src="img/icons/logomini.png" alt="">
  -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/barra-menu.css">
      <header class="header">
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="btn">
            <a id="btna " href=" "><i class="fa fa-bars " href="# " aria-hidden="true "></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="imga ">
            <a href="home.html "><img src="img/icons/logomini.png "></a>
          </div>
          <div class="banner "><a href="home.html ">Over Visual Studio</a></div>
          <nav class="links " href=" ">
            <a id="a " href="home.html "><i class="fa fa-home " aria-hidden="true "></i> Inicio</a>
            <a href="works.html "><i class="fa fa-briefcase " aria-hidden="true "></i> Trabajos</a>
            <a href="news.html "><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o " aria-hidden="true "></i> Noticias</a>
            <a href="form.html "><i class="fa fa-user-circle " aria-hidden="true "></i> Contacto</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <script src="java/menu.js "></script>
      </header>
      <!--Modulo para los Articulos-->
      <link rel="stylesheet " href="css/main.css ">
      <section class="main ">
        <div class="post ">
          <article class="art ">
            <h2>Articulo</h2>
            <hr>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti at doloremque reprehenderit quo laborum ad quis doloribus sed? Maiores optio, dolorum excepturi sint nostrum sed. Velit aliquam officia tenetur quaerat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
              amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti at doloremque reprehenderit quo laborum ad quis doloribus sed? Maiores optio, dolorum excepturi sint nostrum sed.</p>
          </article>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

También traté con el evento onclick y nada, el código mantiene a la vista los menús en modo SamartPhone, quiero que se muestren así pero al momento de que le de click al icono del menú (las tres rayas horizontales de la `<div class="btn""><a id="btna" href=""><i class="fa fa-bars" href="#" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>`)

Este es el archivo CSS del menú ya que trabajo en una pagina que como dice sea modular y pueda quitar y poner los elementos sin tener que reconstruir toda la pag.

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
 z-index: 1000;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.65);
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

a {
 font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.imga {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 padding: 0.5%;
}

.imga img {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
}

.menu {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.btn {
 font-size: 35px;
 color: #EFEFEF;
 display: none;
}
.btn a {
 color: #EFEFEF;
}
.banner {
 font-size: 35px;
 float: left;
 padding: 0.5%;
}

.banner a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #EFEFEF;
 padding: 2%;
}


.links {
 color:#EFEFEF;
 font-size: 20px;
 float: right;
 padding: 0.4%;
 margin: 0.4%;
}

.links a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #EFEFEF;
 padding: 10px;
}

.links a:hover {
 background-color: #5000AD;
 border-radius: 40px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.8s ease;
 transition: all 0.8s ease;
 animation: loop 2s infinite linear alternate;
}

@-moz-keyframes loop {
 0% {color: white;}
 100% {color: #5000AD;}
}

/*Vista para Tablet*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 .banner a {
  display: none;
 }
}

/*Vista Pra Telefono*/

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
 .banner a{
  display: none;
 }
 .links a{
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  border-bottom: black solid 1px;
  margin-right: 15%;
  display: block;
 }
 /*agrego un border top al boton de inicio*/
 #a{
  border-top: black solid 1px;
 }
 .imga {
  display: inline-block;
 }
 .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 8%;
  margin-top: 2%;
 }
}
```

Finalmente los codigo JavaScript que intentado usar:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.links').css({
        document.getElementById('links').style.display="block";
    });
});


// Este otro tambien lo trate de usar.

$(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1;

function main (){
 $('.btna').click(function(){
  //$('nav').toggle();/

  if (contador == 1) {
   $('.links')document.getElementById(".links").style.display="block";
   contador = 0;
  } else {
   contador = 1;
   $('.links')document.getElementById(".links").style.display="none";
  } 
 });
};
```

Comment: Creo que te ha faltado agregar el CSS de los menús. Además, no has añadido nada del JS que has intentado, por lo que no podemos ver si hay algún error en esa parte.

Comment: Gracias por darte cuenta de ello ya lo corregí, y bueno coloque 2 códigos javascript que trate de usar, pero use en realidad como 6 códigos diferentes y pues opte por preguntarle a las personas que si saben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada te recomiendo que indages un poco mas, si usas jquery haz todo con jquery pero si usas vanilla js(js puro) no trates de ligarlos porque en muchos casos dara muchos errores, .css de jquery recibe dos parametros si quieres dar un estilo, y uno si quieres obtener un estilo dd un elemento, si quieres asignar un display none a #links con jquery tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
$(".btn").on('click',function(){
    $('.links').css("display","block");
});
```

Mientras que con javascript puro es lo siguiente:

```
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click',()=>{
document.querySelector('.links').style.display="block";
});
```

Pero como te dije antes tienes que usar o jquery o vanilla js para evitar errores, lo mismo pasa con la funcion main donde de das click a un boton. Tambien lo siguiente no tiene nada que ver con el tema pero en meta description tienes que poner una descripcion de mas o menos 160 caracteres  (si es que quiere optimizar el seo de tu web)

Comment: Gracias. Bueno tienes razón, si estaba mezclando Jquery con JS en el mismo documento, bueno el código que me propones funciona si el botón para mostrar fuera el <div.links> pero quiero que sea en este caso las 3 famosas rayas horizontales (que no se ven porque no subí mis iconos) que vendrían siendo el <div.btn>, y lo que quiero es que cuando se haga click en <div.btn> los estilos de <div.links> se cambien a {display: "block"} porque ya estará oculto en modo SmartPhone (te comento las clases con ".links" o ".btn" para ahorrar espacio) Gracias por el dato de meta description, no sabia de ello.

Comment: Solo cambia el elmento que esta recibiendo el evento click por .btn , y this por .links, voy a editar los ejemplos

Comment: Disculpa, la consola me arroja ReferenceError: $ is not defined. use este codigo `$(".btn").on('click',function(){
    $('.links').css("display","block");
});`

Comment: Listo lo he solucionado, resulta que no coloque la libreria Jquery al html, ahora todo esta muy bien! El problema resulta ahora en como ocultarlo, he intentado añadir un condicional pero no se realmente como hacerlo, intente con '$(".btn").on('click',function(){
 if ( 'display' == 'none' ) {
    $('.link a').css("display","block");
    } 
    else if ( 'display' == 'block' ) {
        $('.link a').hide();
        }
    $('.links a').css("display","none");
});' pero no creo que estén bien, aun sigo buscando información y tutoriales de como hacer esa condicional con jquery.

Comment: Hay viene la cosa, si lo haces con jquery( que veo que lo estas haciendo) usa .toggle() en vez de .css(), tambien podrias usar .slideToggle(), .show() para mostar y .hide() para ocurtar indaga hacerca de todo eso en jquery, esas funciones reciben un parametro, que es el tiempo espresado en milisegundos, o los parametros slow, fast y faster